# Is it not able to call an fetch method (Rest) in componentDidMount when the child has a web socket connection?

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I have a parent class:

```
class Parent extends Component {
//... constructor with some init state

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getList()
    }

     getList = () => {
        // skip some logic
        this.setState({ callingApi: true }, () => {
            getList()
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ list: data })
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()))
            .finally(() => this.setState({ callingApi: false }))
        })
     }

     render() {
       //some logic
       return (
         <Child list={this.state.list} />)}
  }
```

and the child class:

```
class Child extends Component {
//... constructor with some init state

  componentDidMount(){
    stompClient = Stomp.over(new SockJS("/test"));

        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            stompClient.subscribe('/list', function (message) {
              //some logic
            },{ id: //some logic});
        });
    //...render a table

}
```

When I trigger getList. The error occur:
`Error: InvalidStateError: The connection has not been established yet`

It will be fixed if I use componentWillMount

I want to ask why the error occur and is it safe to use componentWillMount?